# Line Drawing Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, graphics

I wrote a line drawing algorithm using the wu technique. It works but has issues. See below.

What I'm wondering is if anyone has tackled the problem of drawing anti-aliased lines?  Suprisingly, a google search results in no satisfactory algorithms.  Lots of discusions, but not a single complete, robust algorithm, independent of any dependencies on a graphics library.

If anyone wants sample code for the following function let me know. I'm hoping to replace this with a more robust function, but I have not found one yet.  I'm sure that my algorithm can be improved, but it works.

```
struct xya
{
    int x;
    int y; 
    uint8_t a;
    xya(int x=0, int y=0, uint8_t a=0) : x(x), y(y), a(a) {}
};

inline void wuline(xya*& out, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    short DeltaX, DeltaY, XDir;
    static const int intensity = 8;

    if (y0 > y1)
    {
        short Temp = y0; 
        y0 = y1; 
        y1 = Temp;
        Temp = x0; 
        x0 = x1; 
        x1 = Temp;
    }

    *out++ = xya(x0,y0,255);

    if ((DeltaX = x1 - x0) >= 0)
    {
        XDir = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        XDir = -1;
        DeltaX = -DeltaX; 
    }

    if ((DeltaY = y1 - y0) == 0)
    {
        while (DeltaX-- != 0) 
        {
            x0 += XDir;
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0,255);            
        }

        return;
    }

    if (DeltaX == 0) 
    {
        do 
        {
            y0++;
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0,255);            
        } 
        while (--DeltaY != 0);

        return;
    }

    if (DeltaX == DeltaY) 
    {
        do 
        {
            x0 += XDir;
            y0++;
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0,255);            
        } 
        while (--DeltaY != 0);

        return;
    }

    if (DeltaY > DeltaX) 
    {
        unsigned short ErrorAcc = 0;  
        unsigned short ErrorAdj = ((unsigned long) DeltaX > intensity;
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0,Weighting ^ 255);
            *out++ = xya(x0+XDir,y0,Weighting);
        }

        *out++ = xya(x1,y1,255);            
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned short ErrorAcc = 0;  
        unsigned short ErrorAdj = ((unsigned long) DeltaY > intensity;
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0,Weighting ^ 255);            
            *out++ = xya(x0,y0+1,Weighting);
        }

        *out++ = xya(x1,y1,255);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your criteria for satisfaction?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical example for drawing antialiased lines quickly and efficiently is **[Xiaolin Wu's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)**. You may want to look at that for a solid approach. Here's [**some sample code**](http://www.suchit-tiwari.org/antialias.html), too. The result of applying Wu's algorithm is on the right:

[alt text http://www.suchit-tiwari.org/writings/antialias/antialias.png](http://www.suchit-tiwari.org/writings/antialias/antialias.png)

Comment: Link is dead, long live the link.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious why aren't you using a library to do this for you?  For example on windows GDI+ supports antialiasing, and I'm sure that there is probably an implementation for QT & WX.  Aside from those options, OpenGL would do the trick too.

GDI+ docs on anti-aliasing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535723%28VS.85%29.aspx

If you are doing it for the heck of it or academic, then just ignore me..

Answer (score 0):

I was once given the task of drawing all sorts of complex and overlapping shapes that needed anti-aliasing. My solution was to draw everything to memory at a higher resolution (2x? 3x?) than the image that needed to be displayed. Then as a last step convert the high res image to low res by averaging the R,G and B separately for each of the multiple pixels in the high res version that would be reduced to a single pixel in the display image.

It may not be the most efficient way of doing things, but its dead easy to code and the visual effect was excellent.

Comment: That's basically a naive implementation of 2xFSAA, which is valid albeit there being better alternatives. Notice that Wu's algorithm has better precision than that.